# I have a confusion if any methods are declared in class extension are static or not

Tags: ios, swift, swift-protocols, swift-extensions, swift-class

```
class Test: UIViewController{

    func abc() {
        print("This is ABC")
    }
}

extension Test {
    func def(){
        print("This is DEF")
     }
}
```

My question here is that

1. what is the difference between both the methods declared?
2. Is method def a static method?
3. extending class to use protocols effects memory management?

Comment: read this document: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Extensions.html

Comment: Its depends on your creativity to organize your code. Btw, defining a function inside extension does not make it static.

Comment: Thanks for the link @MoayadAlkouz. I did read it earlier.

The main concern is that Android said that iOS must not use extensions because the methods declared in extension are static and memory does not release.

All iOS projects uses extension at some point and i have personally never faced any performance related issue.

Is there anything that can explain them better?

Comment: @Nizzam I am using extension as below:
extension AddDealsVC: FloatingMenuPressed{
    func buttonPressed(isImage: Bool, isCamera: Bool, isVideo: Bool) {
        switch true {
        case isImage:
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}

Comment: @VeeralArora A method it its only static if you add the static keyword in front of its declaration otherwise it will be a public instance method as default and it doesn't make a difference if you declare it inside an extension or not

Answer (score 0):

`what is the difference between both the methods declared?`

None, except two things

1. one prints `ABC` and another `DEF`, they have different names
2. you won't be able to override the method from the extension

`Is method def a static method?`

Nope, for this, you should say `static`

`extending class to use protocols effects memory management?`

Nope